# Access to a Docker Gitlab instance from the network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm installing a Gitlab instance with docker-compose on a server machine on my local network, and I'd like to access to my Gitlab instance from anywhere in my local network by visiting for example "https://my-hostname"

I follow [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/).

**I'm running:**

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
      # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
  ports:
    - '7780:80'
    - '7443:443'
    - '7722:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Now I have very (very) limited network knowledge, so basically, how do I access to my running gitlab instance ? When I go to the local network IP of my host, my browser tells me that it can't connect.

**Here is what I'm hoping to achieve:**

```
 LOCAL NETWORK
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                                          |
 |   +--------------------+                                                 |
 |   |     My_Server      |                                                 |
 |   |                    |                                                 |
 |   | +----------------+ |                                                 |
 |   | |                | |  "https://my-hostname" +-------------------+    |
 |   | | Docker: Gitlab | <------------------------+     My_Client     |    |
 |   | |                | |                        +-------------------+    |
 |   | +----------------+ |                                                 |
 |   |                    |                                                 |
 |   +--------------------+                                                 |
 |                                                                          |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: For starters you will need to change the `external_url` to your external url (e.g. `https://my-hostname`).

Answer (score 0):

The `ports` part of your configuration maps the host's ports to the container's ports.

So if you have

> ports:
>      - '7780:80'
>      - '7443:443'
>      - '7722:22'

that is redirecting port 7780 on your host to port 80 on your container, and so forth. You should be able to access your container's services (via its local IP address, and then its hostname via local DNS) with this knowledge.